# Pandas find max value from series of mixed data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-datareader

Am using Pandas df and in dataframe i was able to extract to series named **'xy'** that look like this:

```
    INVOICE
2014-08-14 00:00:00
4557
Printing
nan 
Item    AMOUNT
nan
1   9.6 
0
0
0
9.6
2
11.6
nan 
nan
nan
```

what i need to find is maximum value which is usually located towards the end of 'xy' pandas series i tried to convert it to string i get into problems as some of the series are string not int or float i need a good way as i am writing this script for several different files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `pd.to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(xy, 'coerce').max()

4557.0
```

---

to get the last float number

```
s = pd.to_numeric(xy, 'coerce')
s.loc[s.last_valid_index()]
```

Comment: is there a way to get 11.6 which would always be the last float number in the series

Comment: Select the last float value in pandas series

Comment: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <type 'float'>

Comment: so apparently my xy index are NaN thats why this wont work ;( is there a way to fix it

Comment: Solved : xy = xy.reset_index(drop=True)